# VBA - How to handle an error of Name function

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

Please advise - I wrote a code in `VBA` that iterates through files in certain directory, rename them, and write the status to `Excel`.
I would like to edit the code so that if the command `Name` `returns error` (For example if `NewFileName` already exists), then the parameter `status` would be `"Fail"`, and continue to the next iteration. Could anyone help me how to do so?

```
Sub RenameFiles()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim directory As String
Dim OldFileName As String
Dim NewFileName As String
Dim illegal As String
Dim legal As String
Dim status As String

directory = (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Range("G6").Value) & "\"
illegal = (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Range("G8").Value)
legal = (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Range("G10").Value)

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(directory)
i = 1

'loops through each file in the directory and rename them
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

    OldFileName = objFile.Name
    NewFileName = Replace(OldFileName, illegal, legal)

    'Rename
    Name directory & OldFileName As directory & NewFileName

    'print old file name
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = OldFileName

    'print new file name
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = NewFileName

    'print new file path
    Cells(i + 1, 3) = directory & NewFileName

    'print status
    If (OldFileName <> NewFileName) Then
        status = "Success"
    'Ifelse ()
    Else
        status = "No Change"

    End If
    Cells(i + 1, 3) = status
        i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use the `Dir` function (or a File System Object) to check if a file exists ahead of time, and avoid getting an "error" in the first place. This is the preferred way to handle it.

Comment: You could even prompt the user and ask them if they want to replace it or not, and if not, you can skip it, or jump out of the loop, cancelling the operation altogether.

Comment: I don't want to ask the user, I just would like to skip it and point that out in the result file in excel.

Comment: OK - Handle it however you like. You could also ask them before the loop starts if they would like to replace any that exists, and put that in the result Excel file.